# Now can I add a corner triangle to a moving slide?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, slider

I am using Bootstrap 4 Slider, and I would like to apply the following CSS that works separately:

```css
.container-p{
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  position:relative;
  background-color:grey;
}

.corner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid #ffcc00;
  border-bottom: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  float: right;
  right:0;
}

.corner span {
  position:absolute;
  top: -220px;
  width: 250px;
  left: -220px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display:block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-p">
  <div class="corner"><span>Comercio local</span></div>
</div>
```

The thing is that I would like to apply to 'carousel-item' this triangle so my slider at full screen shows the category of each slide. To do this I include class corner next to carousel-item.

```
<div class="carousel-item corner"></div>
```

but all I get is a white background.

What am I doing wrong?

PD: The content of each slide is a picture with a few words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Yes***, You can add easily triangle shape on each slides or indivisual slide. Your css code is correct but need to add **top:0** in **.corner** class.
Below snippet is working with use of your css code.

```css
.corner {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid #ffcc00;
  border-bottom: 300px solid transparent;
  border-left: 300px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  float: right;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
}
.corner span {
  position:absolute;
  top: -220px;
  width: 250px;
  left: -220px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display:block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x650/CCCCCC" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="corner"><span>Comercio local</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x650/0000FF" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x650/00FFFF" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              <div class="corner"><span>Comercio local</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x650/f1f1f1" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```